# How to create a random graph in networkx from an existing list

Tags: random, graph, networkx

Using **Networkx** to generate a connected graph from an existing list.

Requires:

1. Graph generated must connected but it is not required to be fully connected.
2. The graph must be generated from the existing list.
3. It is better to use existing networkx functions.

Examples with pictures

***[9, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]*** is the list I have used to generate graphs, and it is required to be able to select the nodes according to the given length Generate graph

[image]

**There is only one requirement for adding edges: the generated graph must be a *connected graph***

Comment: This sounds a bit open-ended. For example, `nx.from_edgelist(itertools.combinations(lst, 2))` will generate a complete graph where `lst` is a list of node labels. Do you want the resulting graph to be randomized somehow?

Comment: Any random graph is fine. For example, I now have a list like [9, 5, 7, 4, 2, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]. I hope these elements from index 0 to 7 can be Generate a connected undirected graph. That is, edges are randomly generated from these 8 nodes, and these edges connect at least these 8 nodes. In other words, more than 7 edges are randomly generated from these 8 nodes, and not all connected. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Consider adding your example and the details about the random generation to the question itself.

Comment: I have added a example of the problem, please help me.